# Font feature +frac not applied on EBGaramond italic

Tags: fontspec, fractions, ebgaramond

I'm running into a problem using the `+frac` feature in italic text, though it seems to me that it should work. The feature doesn't seem to be applied properly unless I force the text into `\upshape`.

It does work for some fractions (1/2) but not others (7/8).

[image: r]

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\newcommand\fracA[1]{{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+frac}#1}}
\newcommand\fracB[1]{{\upshape\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+frac}#1}}

\begin{document}

fracA doesn't change font shape:

\begin{enumerate}
\item Some regular text with a fraction: \fracA{7/8}
\item \emph{Some text in italics with a fraction: \fracA{7/8}} --- this doesn't seem to apply the +frac feature?
\item Some regular text with a fraction: \fracA{1/2}
\item \emph{Some text in italics with a fraction: \fracA{1/2}} --- this does work, the fraction is italic.
\end{enumerate}

fracB forces upshape, which makes the frac work but loses the italics:

\begin{enumerate}
\item Some regular text with a fraction: \fracB{7/8}
\item \emph{Some text in italics with a fraction: \fracB{7/8}}
\item Some regular text with a fraction: \fracB{1/2}
\item \emph{Some text in italics with a fraction: \fracB{1/2}}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The feature is indeed available in all the variants, including italic:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/ebgaramond $ otfinfo -f * | ack frac
EBGaramond-Bold.otf:frac    Fractions
EBGaramond-BoldItalic.otf:frac  Fractions
EBGaramond-ExtraBold.otf:frac   Fractions
EBGaramond-ExtraBoldItalic.otf:frac Fractions
EBGaramond-Italic.otf:frac  Fractions
EBGaramond-Medium.otf:frac  Fractions
EBGaramond-MediumItalic.otf:frac    Fractions
EBGaramond-Regular.otf:frac Fractions
EBGaramond-SemiBold.otf:frac    Fractions
EBGaramond-SemiBoldItalic.otf:frac  Fractions
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While Georg Duffner’s EB Garamond supports arbitrary fractions in its italic, Octavio Pardo’s reworking of it, found in TeX Live, supports only a few precomposed fractions (½, ¼, and ¾).

Comment: Aha, it does indeed work if I do `\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{EB Garamond}`. Thanks! :)